# Adding user to MySQL database in php using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I think I am successfully connecting to my database by:

```
<?php
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '9KSroMDjEqNmEYY4';
    $db = 'chatservice';
    $host = '127.0.0.1';

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db, 3306) or die("Unable to connect");
    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

My question is how I would use the registration code to successfully add a user to the database. When entering the form I press register I do not get any error messages stating that the registration didn't succeed. It seems that the php code is not being reached after the initial connection. I am new to php and mySQL so any tips on formatting would be nice too!

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $id = $_POST['IDNUM'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (user ,IDNUM ,password) VALUES('$user', '$id', '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        if($result){
            $msg = "Registered Sussecfully";
            echo $msg;
        }
        else
            $msg = "Error Registering";
            echo $msg;
    }
?>


<div class="register-form">
    <title>Chat Page Start</title>
    <form action="" methods="POST">
        <p>
        <label>Username: </label>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="user" placeholder="user" />
        </p>

        <p>
        <label>ID: </label>
        <input id="IDNUM" type="text" name="IDNUM" placeholder="ID number" />
        </p>

        <p>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        </p>

        <a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a>
        <input class="btn register" type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Another thing is how would I check the status of my database connection and where I should be checking this status?

Comment: Your `or die("Unable to connect")`  won't do anything, because `new mysqli`  will always return an object. You need to test for an connection error using `$mysqli->connect_error`. Beside that you should never do `('$user', '$IDNUM', '$password')`  without escaping those values, you should use prepared statments instead.

Comment: If you are not connecting to DB through `root` username, So you can change `username` and `password` from mysql config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your database connection is mysqli_connect and you execute the query in mysql_query is not proper.

```
 <?php
    require('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $id = $_POST['IDNUM'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (user ,IDNUM ,password) VALUES('$user', ' $id ', '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($query,$conn);
        if($result){
            $msg = "Registered Sussecfully";
        }
        else
            $msg = "Error Registering";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting database using `mysqli`:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db, 3306) or die("Unable to connect");
```

And executing query using `mysql`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (user ,IDNUM ,password) VALUES('$user', '$IDNUM', '$password')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```